# React router doesn't update sub components params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

In my React application, I have trouble making a sub-component update based on props.
the sub-component gets the props from a `<Link/>` tag that is exposed to store state

```
const CallPortfolioManagement= (props) => {
  const { portfolio } = props;
  return (
    <div>
<Link
to={{pathname: `/portfolios/${portfolio.name}`,state: { portfolio: portfolio},}}>
      {portfolio.name}</Link>
    </div>
  );
};


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    portfolio: getPortfolio(state),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CallPortfolioManagemnt);
```

the PortfolioManagement component is:

```
const PortfolioManagement = (props) => {
  const portfolio = useLocation().state.portfolio;
  return (
    <> 
{portfolio.stocks.map((stock, index) => (
   <div key={stock.symbol}>
      <h1>
       {stock.symbol}
      </h1>
   </div>
  ))}
  </>
  );
};
export default PortfolioManagement;
```

a component that got a direct subscription to the state and rerenders when a new stock symbol is added:

```
const RenderLastStock= (props) => {

  const renderLast () => {
    var stocks;
    if (props.portfolio) {
      stocks = props.portfolio["stocks"];
      return <button>{stocks[stocks.length - 1]].symbol}</button>;
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      renderLast ()}
    </>
  );
};
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { tasks: getLoadingTasks(state), portfolios: getPortfolios(state) };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(RenderLastStock);
```

the route declared here and calls PortfolioManagement when clicked:

```
function App(props) {
 useEffect(() => {
    props.getPortfolios();
  }, []);
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
            <PrivateRoute>     
              <Route path="/portfolios/:id" component={PortfolioManagement} />
            </PrivateRoute>
        </Switch> </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

the problem is that PortfolioManagement **gets the params but does no rerender when the state is changed** - when I add stock symbols.
I update the store's state with Object.assign and **other components that are subscribed to this state do rerender!** (so there aren't any immutability problems)

looking in the redux devtools I can see the state is updated correctly, I suspect that PortfolioManagement does not rerender because react does not refer to Link's Params as props and does not know it should trigger a rerender.

please help:(

Comment: Would you be able to add the component which is rendering PortfolioManagement please?

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `useLocation`, you can use `withRouter` at `PortfolioManagement` -

---

```
  import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

  const PortfolioManagement = (props) => {
      console.log(props.location && props.location.state) 
   ...rest code...
 }
  export default withRouter(PortfolioManagement);
```

---

I know its hacky, but anyhow now `state` comes from `props` and component will re-render

**Edit**

The usage of `Link` and the `state` location object you can send with, works on a way that the context won't be exist if the component wasn't called through the link, consider send the props through regular props at `Router` decoration (that I assuming is a component connected to redux store)

---

```
<Route path="/portfolios/:id" render={()=> <PortfolioManagement props={...props} />} />
```

---

Comment: didn't work:(
maybe I should have pass parameters in a different way than ```<Link
to={{pathname: `/portfolios/${portfolio.name}`,state: { portfolio: portfolio},}}>```

Comment: Can you add `getProtfolio` to your question? Because the way you use `Link` actually looks good...

Comment: still not working, maybe i need to call the link in a different way?
```  <Link
to={{pathname: `/portfolios/${portfolio.name}`,state: { portfolio: portfolio},}}>
      {portfolio.name}</Link>```

added the call to getPortfolios, its just a simple selector the get the state. it works

Answer (score 0):

didn't find a solution with react router, I solved it by cheating and giving portfolioManagement direct access to the store